# Spring REST multiple @RequestBody parameters, possible?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I've implemented a Spring RESTful web service. Using Jackson JSON for Object Mapping. I have a method that accepts two parameters.

```
public Person createPerson(
    @RequestBody UserContext userContext,
    @RequestBody Person person)
```

How would the client construct a request where in multiple JSON objects are to be passed in the body?

Is this possible?

-- Sri

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that won't work. There may be a workaround, but the much easier way would be to introduce a wrapper Object and change your signature:

```
public class PersonContext{
    private UserContext userContext;
    private Person person;
    // getters and setters
}


public Person createPerson(@RequestBody PersonContext personContext)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm considering a wrapper Array as the last resort. What is the work around you were referring to?

Comment: @Srirangan: the workarround is the PersonContext class - it is some kind of DTO

Comment: @Srirangan I said there *may* be a workaround. I am not aware of one myself

Comment: @Sri,  nevertheless thank you for asking it, it helps us that have to pick up Spring quickly because of being thrown in at the deep end. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12893566/2114313) is similar and has a more detailed answer, you might want to link.

Comment: Is it be possible to set a custom Jackson deserializer for an object/instance variables inside of PersonContext?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat sure, just annotate any field with [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) with a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) implementation