# AngularJS REST POST multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

How can I make REST POST call in AngularJS, when there are multiple arguments? Here's simple example:

Java REST service (server side):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody Person person, @RequestBody int maxPeople) {
    service.create(person, maxPeople);
}
```

AngularJS REST factory (client side):

```
app.factory('PersonService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/person/create', {}, {
        save: { method: 'POST'}
    });
});
```

Angular controller:

```
app.controller('PersonController', function (PersonService) {
    PersonService.save({"name": "John"}, 2);
});
```

The crucial fragment is: `PersonService.save({"name": "John"}, 2);`
This one doesn't work, I can't figure out how to pass there multiple parameters. What is the correct approach?

Comment: post the code in your `$resource` definition. basically, for `$resource`, there is only one argument, with as many properties in the object. your case would probably be `{name: 'john', id: 2}` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

[Alright, I just realised that we shouldn't have multiple @RequestBody parameters in a method...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)

Therefore my problem seems to be solved, it was more server-side issue, we just have to hold all arguments in the one json.