# Spring: request-payload with only one element

Tags: java, spring

I want implement a web-service which consumes only one named parameter in request-payload. In curl view it should be smth like:
curl -X PATCH myurl.net/my_service -d "{mySingleParameter: 49}"

I'm trying to do it with Spring, but I wondered that to map such payload to my method I must to declare a new class. Like:

```
...
public static class PayloadWithSingleParamMSP{
  public Long mySingleParameter;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "my_service", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public String myService(@RequestBody PayloadWithSingleParamMSP payload){
  Long valueWhichIReallyNeed = payload.mySingleParameter;
  //do job
  ...
}
...
```

But is there a way to take value which I really need (mySingleParameter) directly?

Answer (score 4):

You have couple options:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "my_service", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public String myService(@RequestBody ObjectNode payload){
        Long valueWhichIReallyNeed = payload.get("mySingleParameter").asLong();
        //do job
       ...
    }
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "my_service", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public String myService(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload){
    Long valueWhichIReallyNeed = Long.parseLong(payload.get("mySingleParameter"));
    //do job
    ...
}
```

or even

```
@RequestMapping(value = "my_service", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public String myService(@RequestBody  Long mySingleParameter){
    Long valueWhichIReallyNeed = mySingleParameter;
    //do job
    //  ...
}
```

but in this last case your curl will look following:

```
curl -X PATCH myurl.net/my_service -d "49"
```

In answers for this question you can find more options: [Passing multiple variables in @RequestBody to a Spring MVC controller using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)