# Not able to receive parameters using Postmapping in Rest Controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-restcontroller

My `Ajax` code looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : url,
    async : false,  
    data: {'txToClose': '1234,5678','sno':'0195'},
    contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : "json",      
    success : function(result,status,xhr){
        console.log(result);

    }                           
});
```

The **txToClose** value 1234,5678 will be coming from a textbox as comma separated string. The user will type them as comma separated.

Im trying to receive them in `controller` as

```
@PostMapping("/txToClose")  
public ResultDto txToClose(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws BBException
{
    logger.info("Called txToClose controller");
    ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();

    String txToClose= request.getParameter("txToClose");
    String sno= request.getParameter("sno");

    logger.info("Transactions to close :"+txToClose+", Serial Num :"+sno);
}
```

### Output is

> Transactions to close :null, Serial Num :null

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're posting your data as request body, which of course using `request.getParameter()` will give you `null`. getParameter() was used to retrieve value from URL parameter.

I'm not quite experience with SpringMVC but try to change your method parameter into

```
public ResultDto txToClose(@RequestBody ResultDto resultDto ) throws BBException
{
    logger.info("Called txToClose controller");

    String txToClose= resultDto.getTxtToClose();
    String sno= resultDto.getSno();

    logger.info("Transactions to close :"+txToClose+", Serial Num :"+sno);
}
```

I assume your `ResultDto` is same as your JSON format.

Comment: you mean my ResultDto should have txToClose & sno?

Comment: Yes, and if you don't want to mapping your JSON into ResultDto, you can check this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897632/5852226

Comment: It worked when I have my signature as public ResultDto txToClose(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody ObjectNode json)

Answer (score 0):

remove the line

contentType : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",

or use default contentType

contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",

It should work.

Comment: Just to debug, try once with 

@RequestMapping(value="/txToClose")
@ResponseBody

public ResultDto txToClose(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws BBException
{
    logger.info("Called txToClose controller");
    ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();

    String txToClose= request.getParameter("txToClose");
    String sno= request.getParameter("sno");

    logger.info("Transactions to close :"+txToClose+", Serial Num :"+sno);
}

Comment: Solved it. By  adding ,@RequestBody ObjectNode json

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding @RequestBody ObjectNode json in the signature.

```
public ResultDto txToClose(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody ObjectNode json) throws BBException
{
    logger.info("Called txToClosecontroller");
    ResultDto result = new ResultDto();

    String txToClose= json.get("txToClose").asText();
}
```