# Spring boot rest controller not converting request body to custom object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have spring boot application which used spring rest controller . 
 This is the controller , below is the response an getting. Am using postman tool for sending request to this controller. And am sending content type as application/json

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestBody WebApp webapp, @RequestBody String propertyFiles, @RequestBody String) {
    System.out.println("webapp :"+webapp);
    System.out.println("propertyFiles :"+propertyFiles);
    System.out.println("propertyText :"+propertyText);

    return "ok good";
}
```

2018-03-21 12:18:47.732  WARN 8520 --- [nio-8099-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed

This is my postman request

```
{
"webapp":{"webappName":"cavion17","path":"ud1","isQA":true},
"propertyFiles":"vchannel",
"propertytText":"demo property"}
```

I tried by removing the RequestBody annotation, then able to hit the service , but param objects are received as null.

So please suggest how to retrieve objects in the restcontroller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use multiple `@RequestBody` annotations in Spring. You need to wrap all these in an object.

Some like this

```
// some imports here
public class IncomingRequestBody {
    private Webapp webapp;
    private String propertryFiles;
    private String propertyText;

    // add getters and setters here
}
```

And in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestBody IncomingRequestBody requestBody) {
    System.out.println(requestBody.getPropertyFiles());
    // other statement
    return "ok good";
}
```

Read more here
[Passing multiple variables in @RequestBody to a Spring MVC controller using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)

Comment: Suppose if want to assign values only for propertryFiles alone. How to accept?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample postman payload you gave, you will need:

```
public class MyObject {

    private MyWebapp  webapp;
    private String propertyFiles;
    private String propertytText;

    // your getters /setters here as needed
}
```

and

```
public class MyWebapp {
    private String webappName;
    private String path;
    private boolean isQA;

    // getters setters here
}
```

Then on your controller change it to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestBody MyObject payload) {
    // then access the fields from the payload like
    payload.getPropertyFiles();

    return "ok good";
}
```