# How to pass 2 objects in @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Could you help me to solve a problem with passing two objects through @RequestBody?
As far as I know you can't pass 2 @RequestBody parameters, so I've created `Tuple` class to store custom data. 
In my case I need to pass a `Book` object and int value in json representation. I've already tried different ways but each time it cannot be parsed aright.

```
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @ToString
    public final class Tuple<K, V> {
        private K key;
        private V value;
    }
```

I use `Tuple` in this method.

```
    @PutMapping("action/returnBook")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> returnBook(@RequestBody final Tuple<Long, Long> userIdBookInstanceId) {
        leasingHistoryService.returnBook(userIdBookInstanceId.getKey(), userIdBookInstanceId.getValue());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @ToString
    public final class Book {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        private String title;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
        private Author author;

    }

    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @ToString
    public final class Author {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        private String name;

        private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

        private String bio;
   }
```

What is the structure of the json that I should pass in the `PUT` request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I think it won't work with generic types. You should create i.e. ReturnBookRequest class with Book property and int property and then pass this class to RequestBody

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple variables in @RequestBody to a Spring MVC controller using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)

Comment: you cant. check includedlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it.
In this case it's the following json:

```
{
    "key" : {
        "title": "The Girl in the Spider's Web v17",
        "author": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Larsson",
            "dateOfBirth": "1954-08-15",
            "bio": "Author of the Millennium trilogy"
        }
    },
    "value": 3
}
```