# Is it possible to pass multiple objects in @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Is it possible to pass multiple objects in @RequestBody?

I need it in order to get rid of bicycles inventions and creating utility classes.

Comment: Maybe duplication.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430855/how-to-pass-2-objects-in-requestbody

Comment: Please provide more details about the questions. What you want is two objects of @RequestBody. If so how does your request look like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here i am assuming that you want to send two class objects in a single responsebody response.

Create an additional inner class in your Controller that resembles both the entities

```
static class UserAndProfile {
    public UserProfile userprofile;
    public User user;
}
and then your request mappings would resemble

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserAndProfile user()  {
    UserAndProfile userAndProfile = new UserAndProfile();
    userAndProfile.userprofile = ...
    userAndProfile.user = ...
    return userAndProfile;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object user(@RequestBody UserAndProfile userAndProfile) {
    ...
}
```