# How to call an endPoint in curl that is having two request body parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl

I have defined a method like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/multiRquestBody",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String multiRquestBodyMethod(@RequestBody String[] body1,@RequestBody String[] body2){
        System.out.println("body1 : "+body1);
        System.out.println("body 2 : "+body2);
        return Arrays.toString(body1)+"------"+Arrays.toString(body2);
    }
```

I used curl command like this to call that method

```
curl -X POST  "http://localhost:7979/choudhury-rest/rest/book/multiRquestBody"     -d '["test","test","test"],["testing","testing string array"]' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Then I got an error like this

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

I have tried another way like

```
curl -X POST  "http://localhost:7979/choudhury-rest/rest/book/multiRquestBody"     -d '["test","test","test"]&["testing","testing string array"]' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

But still, the same issue is coming
how can I solve it

Comment: This is probably a duplicated post, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple variables in @RequestBody to a Spring MVC controller using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

@RequestBody should ideally be used only once in the method and hold the entire body of the request. In your case, you can create an object that holds the two string arrays, so something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/multiRquestBody",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String multiRquestBodyMethod(@RequestBody StringArraysBody body){
    System.out.println("body1 : "+body.getBody1());
    System.out.println("body 2 : "+body.getBody2());
    return Arrays.toString(body.getBody1())+"------"+Arrays.toString(body.getBody2());
}

public class StringArraysBody {
   String[] body1;
   String[] body2;

   public String[] getBody1() {
     return body1;
   }

   public String[] getBody2() {
     return body2;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply
I know this approach, but I got the requirement to define a method ( same as in the question ) 
and I need to call it
So is there any way