# How to get only one String parameter from request in Java?

Tags: java, json, post, jackson, jax-rs

I've created POST method:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @JsonView({ TestView.class })
    public Response test(@Valid String testParameter) {
        return testController.doTest(testParameter);
    }
```

In request I'm sending one parameter:

```
{
  "testParameter": "Hello"
}
```

which I want to map to "testParameter" parameter in method. Class consumes / produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. There's any available annotation which can allow me to get this parameter?
Or do I have to remap the entire JSON(String) and get this value?

Comment: there are multiple options described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a request object class with a single String field called `testParameter`.
Replace the `String` parameter with this request object and retrieve your value from it.

Comment: I want to avoid creating special object for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<String, String>` as requestbody if you don't want to create Class.

```
public Response test(Map<String, String> map) {
        return testController.doTest(map.get("testParameter"));
}
```