# POST method and return JSON Object

Tags: java, json, spring

In my main class spring boot, I want to verify the information which are in the method parameters and do some logic to return JSON Object with attribute "code" which contains a value "0"
But I'm getting the 400 bad request in postman.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Hint a screenshot of code (not even included in the original question) isn't a good question.

Comment: @Sara do you call this a question title "POST method and return JSON Object"

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749674/9050514

Comment: I'm sorry I had no idea how to make a post in StackOverFlow
Next time I will make sure to make my posts clear

Comment: @Sara check the link i have posted it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `@RequestBody` twice at same request as there is only one. I guess you have an object called user with the fieldes  as your json. You should change the method signiture to `validateItems(@RequestBody User  user)`
And your json to user:{... Fieldes and values}

Comment: Is it necessery to do this logic in RestController because I did it into the main class ?

Comment: It is necessary to put the logic at controller. I would suggest go through thi guide https://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model class with parameters and pass the Model through the `@RequestBody`

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/signin")
@ResponseBody
public String something(@RequestBody Model myModel) 
{
    return "";
}
```

**Model**

```
class Model {

  private String param1;
  private String param2;

  Model() {}

  Model(String param1, String param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
  }
}
```

Comment: is it okey to write this method into main class ?

Comment: Can you be more specific which method are you talking about?
Create a model class and use the model in your `@RequestBody`

Comment: method post which is in the controller

Comment: Nope.. Write it to the controller class.