# Cannot return html when using post method in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I have a `Controller` class in my spring boot application which has two methods that correspond to `GET` and `POST` requests for the same `url`, When the user makes a get request it returns an `html page` with a form which when submitted makes a `post` request to the same `url`, I'm able to receive the `form data` but the problem is that the application is not returning another page when hitting the `url` with `post`. Instead I'm getting a `WhiteLable` error on the browser and on the console I'm getting this error ->
`DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]`
Below is the code snippet

```
   @Controller
   public class SimpleController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String getRequest()  {
        return "simple.html";
    }

    @PostMapping("/index")
    public String postRequest(String firstName, String lastName) {
        System.out.println("The result is " + firstName + " " + lastName);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        return "simple.html";
    }

   }
```

And this is what my `HTML` code looks like

```
<body>
    <form action="index" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="firstName">
        <input type="text" name="lastName">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you may have forgotten the `@RequestBody` annotation before your parameters.

Comment: However you cannot pass two "RequestBody" parameters at once. You may have to create a Class (like `Person`) which can hold `firstName` and `lastName` values. The mapping will do the rest: `public String postRequest(@RequestBody Person person)` and then `person.getFirstName()`... [This question is about that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12893566/896249)

Comment: in post method try using `return "redirect:/index"` and post your result again @ansme

Comment: @GameDroids Hi I tried with `@RequestBody` but it is giving me `415 Unsupported Media Type` status code, I've also edited the question and have added the `html` content as well kindly check that too.

Comment: @BishalGautam redirecting works! But what if I want to send some other page? For example instead of `simple.html` I want to send `success.html`, Then how should I achieve that?

Comment: generally we only send the prefix or file name that is in the project like `return "simple";`. If you any other views with say `success.html` than just do `return "success"`.

Comment: @BishalGautam AFAIK that works when we are using `thymeleaf`  in dependencies and currently I'm not using it that's why I've also specified the extension of the file, Because `return "success"`, Generates 404 without `thymeleaf`.

Comment: what are you using for the view? @ansme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231892/discussion-between-ansme-and-bishal-gautam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use return `"redirect:/success.html"` so that you can get your html pages. Also from our chat, please use `thymeleaf` which is a *template engine*.
You can add it by adding it in your dependencies in the `pom.xml` file. This is what you should add inside your `dependecies` tag in `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```