POST endpoint to accept multiple parameters
I have the following endpoint which can accept a text body from Swagger UI. How do I add another parameter to it?
@ApiOperation(value = "...", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@PostMapping(value = "handleRequest", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String handleRequest(@Parameter(name = "Request", description = "The body of a request", example = "...") @RequestBody String body) {
  ...
}

I tried the following, and even though the Swagger UI is showing two text boxes, when I submitted, Spring Boot returned 400 Bad Request.
@ApiOperation(value = "...", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@PostMapping(value = "handleRequest", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String handleRequest(@Parameter(name = "Request", description = "The body of a request", example = "...") @RequestBody String body,
                            @Parameter(name = "Request2", description = "The body of a second request", example = "...") @RequestBody String body2) {
  ...
}

Thanks in advance.

You cannot have 2 bodies, the request only has 1 body. Either use parameters @RequestParam or use an object to bind to. But judging from here you just use the wrong annotation and you should have been using @RequestParam all along.

You can't pass two bodies in the request. You can create custom wrapper that will handle multiple values or simply use MultiValueMap<String, String> params and read params accordingly. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12893566/10553411 see this

Currently I have a single text area on Swagger UI to accept a single text message. If I want to have another text area to accept a second text message, is it technically possible?
