Spring - Can I use @RequestBody without a data class and using x-www-urlencoded instead of Json?
Is there a way I can use @RequestBody on a POST endpoint (@PostMapping) and get the values one by one instead of having to create a data class for it?
What I have right now. This works submitting a Json body:
@PostMapping
suspend fun saveUser(
    @RequestBody
    user: UserRequestBody
) : ResponseEntity<Map<String, Any?>> { 
    
    // Process request
    
}

What I want (something similar to @RequestParam). I would like to use x-www-urlencoded for submitting the body if possible:
@PostMapping
suspend fun saveUser(
    @RequestBody
    id: Long,
    @RequestBody
    name: String,
    @RequestBody
    email: String,
) : ResponseEntity<Map<String, Any?>> {

    // Process request

}

I appreciate your help!

is this answering your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897632/2311723 or this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-url-encoded-form-data#nonbrowser_requests

No you cannot and why not use @RequestParam or just @ModelAttribute to bind the parameters?

@antoine.lange Thank you! Using a Map is a good alternative indeed. However, I'm still trying to figure out how to make it work with  x-www-urlencoded.

@M.Deinum Indeed, it seems it is not possible to do it that way. And, regarding using RequestParam, I don't thing it is a good practice to send POST data in the URL.

Again what prevents you from using @ModelAttribute? Why are you so fixated at @RequestBody?
