# "HttpMessageNotReadableException Required request body is missing" when trying to make a post request

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a controller class with a few methods one of which is a method that is supposed to take POST requests and create a new Account with the JSON from the body of that POST request.

When I try to use curl to make the POST request I get an **error that says**

```
{"timestamp":1493988808871,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Required request body is missing: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.example.AccountRestController.add(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)","path":"/users/add"}
```

**The curl command I'm using**

```
curl -X POST --data '{"userName":"bepis", "password":"xyz"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/users/add
```

**AccountRestController**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/add", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody String username, @RequestBody String password) {
    Account result = accountRepository.save(new Account (username, password));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: What if you change to `ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use multiple `@RequestBody`. You need to wrap everything into a class that will be used to match your request body.

The same is answered also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726583/spring-rest-multiple-requestbody-parameters-possible).

There is also a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9434) for a feature request which was rejected.

**NOTE:** if you want to write less, you can use `@PostMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`.

**NOTE:** `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` are used to extract data from URI, not from body.

**NOTE:** the same is valid also for the equivalent `[FromBody]` attribute from `ASP.NET WebAPI`.

**Complete example:**

Bellow I created a working example similar to your case:

**Request DTO**

```
public class AccountCreateRequest {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Response DTO**

```
public class AccountCreateResponse {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public AccountCreateResponse() {
    }

    public AccountCreateResponse(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/account")
public class AccountController {

    @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) AccountCreateResponse add(@RequestBody() AccountCreateRequest account) {
        AccountCreateResponse response = new AccountCreateResponse(account.getUserName(), account.getPassword());
        return response;
    }
}
```

**curl request**

```
curl -X POST --data '{"userName":"bepis", "password":"xyz"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/v1/account
```

Comment: Thanks that let me make the POST request but the variables for userName and password are always null. I changed the method parameters to **@RequestBody Account input**

Comment: @LightningJimmyJoeJohnson take a look at my last edit. I provided a working example for you similar to what you need.

Comment: Why have two classes different classes? Why not use **AccountCreateResponse** for both they seam functionally identical.

Comment: Is just an example to point out request and response objects. You can use as you like. Usually I create separate DTOs for request and response because can handle complex business scenarios and most of the time, in my case, I encountered these two to be different. This introduce complexity but more flexibility. You can use the same class if works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed **@Requestbody**s to a single **@RequestBody** like andreim said, it fixed my bad request error but for some reason the account username would always be **null** when the post request went through.

I messed with a few thing, eventually leading me to swap the order of the Account constructor parameters from

```
Account(String username, String password)
```

to

```
Account(String password, String username)
```

This worked for some reason and let me make my post request with the proper values. Latter out of curiosity I decided to swap the parameters back to `Account(String username, String password)`
and the post request still works as intended.

I have no idea what I did to get rid of the **null** problem but it seams to have worked.

Comment: This is a very old post so maybe I a commenting for no reason but your Controller expects username with `{"username":......}`. Note the cases of username. Earlier you sent `userName`. The capital N was causing mapping issues.